# how to change XLOC ID to Ensembl ID from Cuffdiff

Tags: python

I did RNA-Seq analysis, the GTF file I used was from Ensembl. The output of cuffdiff replaced the Ensembl IDs with XLOC's although it also output gene names (e.g. MX2). Ensembl IDs were no longer there.

I saw a post that showed to modify the merged.gtf using this python script

http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=51071

```
#!/usr/bin/python
gtf_handle = "/PATH/TO/merged.gtf"
fh = open(gtf_handle, "r")
import re
trans_ids = {}
with open('merged2.gtf', 'w') as f:
for line in fh:
line = line.strip('\n') ##strip the line to remove white spaces
##print line
cuffID = re.findall(r'gene_id \"([\w\.]+)"', line) ##use RE to get lists of cuffid, ensemblId etc
cuffTx = re.findall(r'transcript_id \"([\w\.]+)"', line)
ensemblTx = re.findall(r'oId \"([\w\.]+)"', line)
geneName = re.findall(r'gene_name \"([\w\.]+)"', line)
##print cuffTx[0]
line = str(line).replace(cuffTx[0], ensemblTx[0]) ##unlist the transcript identifiers and replace cufflinksID with ensemblIDs
print line
f.write("%s\n" % str(line)) ##write file out to a .gtf file`
```

I followed this script but get an error:

```
File "modify_merge.py", line 12 
  for line in fh: 
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Indentation matters in python.

Answer (score 0):

As @ppperry commented, indentation matters in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
gtf_handle = "/PATH/TO/merged.gtf"
fh = open(gtf_handle, "r")
import re
trans_ids = {}
with open('merged2.gtf', 'w') as f:
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip('\n') ##strip the line to remove white spaces
        ##print line
        cuffID = re.findall(r'gene_id \"([\w\.]+)"', line) ##use RE to get lists of cuffid, ensemblId etc
        cuffTx = re.findall(r'transcript_id \"([\w\.]+)"', line)
        ensemblTx = re.findall(r'oId \"([\w\.]+)"', line)
        geneName = re.findall(r'gene_name \"([\w\.]+)"', line)
        ##print cuffTx[0]
        line = str(line).replace(cuffTx[0], ensemblTx[0]) ##unlist the transcript identifiers and replace cufflinksID with ensemblIDs
        print line
        f.write("%s\n" % str(line)) ##write file out to a .gtf file
```